# How to rolling up category to zero if any of the subcategory missed 100%?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am working on some special request to show zero value if any of the underlying sub category missed the target (100%), I have tried using SUMX but it end up giving all sub categories even though it's not falling under the category group. I am trying to achieve matrix view of it.

[image]

Formulas I have tried,

```
Formula 1
Over 100+:= CALCULATE(Count(ProductID),FILTER(Payout,Payout[Performance%]>=1))


Formula 2
IF(DIVIDE(SUMX(Payout,Payout[ActualPay]),SUMX(Payout,Payout[Risk Amount]))>=1,1,0)
```

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over the table and check if each row has performance greater than 100% and take the minimum over all the rows.

```
Over 100+ = MINX ( Payout, IF ( Payout[Performance%] >= 1, 1, 0 ) )
```

Note that when this is a measure, the table `Payout` is filtered by its local filter context. So in each of the product rows, the table `Payout` passed into `MINX` is only that row.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Alexis, This expression should work as per the current question context.